# Mechanism of Acidity - Boric Acid

Tags: acid-base

How does boric acid behave as an acid? Is it a Lewis acid or a Brønsted-Lowry acid?

Comment: what are your thoughts/ideas on the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boric_acid) says boric acid is a Lewis acid. It later states that it is a tribasic Brønsted acid.

A Brønsted acid is a compound that is able to provide $\ce{H^+}$ ions. A Lewis acid is a compound that can accept an electron pair; it would need to be electron poor. Some molecules have both characteristics and either feature could be used in explaining the reactivity of the compound.

Tribasic means that there are 3 hydrogens that can be used. I'm believe that the author used the term basic acid to mean that the hydrogen is attached as a hydroxyl group instead of hydrogen bonded. Phosphorous acid is always written as $\ce{H3PO3}$, although it could be written as $\ce{P(OH)3}$.

Comment: It also says it's a "tribasic" Bronsted acid. I'm not clear on what that means and it appears there is quite a bit of debate still about its acidity. I just want the best supported answer.

Comment: Yes, but what's a tribasic acid? What's a basic acid?

Comment: The term "basicity" of an acid refers in this context to the number of conjugate bases. $\ce{H3BO3}$, when reacting as a Brönsted acid, is tribasic because the 3 conjugate bases $\ce{H2BO3^-}$, $\ce{HBO3^{2-}}$ and $\ce{BO3^{3-}}$ are formed in the dissociation steps. The term does not imply that the acidic protons are bound to an oxygen (OH group). $\ce{H2S}$, for example, can be described as a weak dibasic Brönsted acid.

Comment: Ah, thank you. There are the HS- and S^2- conjugate bases.

Answer (score 2):

Boric acid is a Lewis acid, therefore when in water it accepts the lone pair from oxygen and becomes $\ce{(OH)3B^{-}-OH2^{+}}$.
From this compound a proton can be donated and this is how boric acid behaves as a Brønsted acid.